# It there other method to show the function $t\mapsto \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+(x+t)^2} dx$ is differentiable for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In order to show that the function $F\colon t\to \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+(x+t)^2} dx$ is differentiable for all $t\in\mathbb{R},$ I make a change of variable of $T\colon ~y=x+t,$ so that
\begin{gather*}
F(t)=\int_0^{-t}\frac{\cos x}{1+(x+t)^2} d x+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(y-t)}{1+y^2} d y=:I(t)+J(t),
\end{gather*}
and hence we need to show $J$ is differentiable for all $t.$
Is it possible to show differentiability of $F,$ without using $T?$